# Hyphens undeleteable from JTextField

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

So I have a JTextField which receives a 10-digit number input and edits the given phone number in this format XXX-XXX-XXXX. 
When one tries to erase past the last four numbers, it is imposible to delete the hyphen. 
I tried to fix this using the KeyTyped method but I found out that BackSpace key can not use this method, only KeyPressed or KeyRelease, so I used the KeyReleased method for it and now it will erase the hyphens, but it will erase more than 1 digit per everytime I hit the backspace key.
If anyone could succesfully accomplish this in a better way that allows to erase only one digit per strike I'm all eyes.

This is the listener for my JTextField:

```
public class PhoneList implements KeyListener {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // Allow Numbers only
            char testChar = e.getKeyChar();
            if (!Character.isDigit(testChar)) {
                e.consume();
            }
            String pnText = pntf.getText();
            int pnLength = pnText.length();
            // Add the hyphens
            if (pnLength == 3 || pnLength == 7) {
                pntf.setText(pnText + "-");
            }
            // Limited to 10-digit numbers
            if (pnLength >= 12) {
                e.consume();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { //Empty  }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // Erase numbers and also hyphens
            boolean released = false;
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE && released == false) {
                String pnTxt = pntf.getText();
                int pnL = pnTxt.length();
                if (pnL > 1) {
                    int start = 0;
                    int end = pnL - 1;
                    String pnErased = pnTxt.substring(start, end);
                    released = true;
                    pntf.setText(pnErased);
                } else {
                    pntf.setText("");
                    released = true;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Never use a KeyListener with a Swing text component. Why not use a JFormattedTextField instead?

Comment: [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)